# MySQL Stored Proc and c# data reader column wrong values

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, sqldatareader, mysql-connect

I have a situation in such a way that variable value has to be returned based on multiple condition.  Initially it is set to passed parameter value. Below is just an algo,

```
    create proc checkFlag (ppleid int,  pflag bit, loginid int)
    begin
declare vflag bit;
declare vhasRights bit;
declare vIsLocked bit;
declare vlockedUid int;

set vflag=pflag;  // assign as passed param


if (vflag = 0)
then
      select id, name,vflag as 'IsEditable'
      from peopletable
      where id=ppleid;
else
-- algo to check whether loginid has rights to edit
          if (vhasrights = 1)  
          then 
              -- sql statements to check whether record is not write locked into vIsAlreadyLocked
                  if (vIsAlreadyLocked = 1)  
                  then 
                     --- sql statements to check whether locked user is login user in vlockedUid 
                    if (vlockedUid = ploginid)
                    then
                        set vflag =1;
                    else
                        set vflag=0;
                    end if;
                  else 
                     set vflag=0;
                  end if;
      select id, name,vflag as 'IsEditable'
      from peopletable
      where id=ppleid;
   end if;
end;
```

A. Sp. call withing sqleditor
call checkflag(values.....);  returns appropriate value

B. Sp. call from c#

```
internal void ReadPpl()
{
     bool initFlag=<flag based on client end condition>;
     . code for creating connection and command of type storedproc
     .
```

> **MysqlParameter prm=new parameter("pflag", initFlag);**

```
    .
    .
    .  cmd.parameter(prm)
    using (mysqldatareader rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      if (rdr.HasRows())
     {
       rdr.Read();
```

> ****bool IsWritable=Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(rdr["IsEditable"])); // This is the line that returns value as passed parameter  but not based on conditions in db and params ****

```
     }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got problem solved.

> call proc(@flag...)

resulted @flag other than 0. So the else condition was executed. 
But

> MySqlParameter prm=new(....,Value=initValue);

considered intiValue as 0 hence,  the only the first if condition in stored proc. was executed every time.